# How to get lighting information on a 2D Sprite's front-side?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm using 2D Sprites for NPCs in a 3D game. My problem is when a sprite NPC turns away from the light source (eg. Directional Light) it becomes completely dark. So for almost 180 degrees when not facing the light source the sprite is all black. I need to prevent this from happening and find a way to set a minimum light/color for my NPCs so the player can see them. What would be a good way to find out how much light is affecting the forward facing side of a gameobject?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I did spend a fair amount of time looking into this for a recent project.

One suggestion that might work is to map the graphics to quads instead of using the sprite renderer, since they will use the 3D-lighting.